# match/merge dataframes with a number columns with different column names in r

Tags: r

I have two dataframe with different columns that has large number of rows (about 2 million)

The first one is df1

[image]

The second one is df2

[image]

I need to get match the values in y column from table one to R column in table two 
Example:
see the two rows in df1 in red box have matched the two rows in df2 in red box
[image]

Then I need to get the score of the matched values

so the result should look like this and it should be stores in a dataframe:

[image]

My attempt : first Im beginner in R, so when I searched I found that I can use Match function, merge function but I did not get the result that I want it might because I did not know how to use them correctly, therefore, I need step by step very simple solution

Comment: Please don't post images of data. Code-formatted print results are ok; [`dput` results are better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` from `base R`

```
df2[match(df2$R, df1$y, nomatch = 0), c("R", "score")]
#   R score
#3   2     3
#4 111     4
```

---

Or another option is `semi_join` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(df2[-1], df1, by = c(R = "y"))
#    R score
#1   2     3
#2 111     4
```

Comment: thanks, that worked but I have another question how do I store the UNmathced ones and get there scores ? (meaning the opposite of what we did )

Comment: @user8863554  For that you need `anti_join` i.e. `anti_join(df2[-1], df1, by = c(R = "y"))`

Comment: one last questions, the values in R column could be numbers, empty (means the cell is empty) , or has NA values. How I can specify the values that I want when I do the match ?

Comment: @user8863554  In that case, `filter` out the values that you don't want and then do the join i.e. `df2[-1] %>% filter(R != "") %>% semi_join(df1, by = c(R = "y"))`

Answer (score 1):

```
 merge(df1,df2,by.x="y",by.y="R")[c("y","score")]
    y score
1   2     3
2 111     4
```

Comment: thanks, that worked but I have another question how do I store the UNmathced ones and get there scores ? (meaning the opposite of what we did )